# Apache CONF: How to add outside directories without showing the location in source

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm having a real brain fart right now, and forgot whats required in httpd.conf to include files from directories outside the web root folder. The whole idea is that I can call files from other folders, without listing the location in the HTML/PHP source files.

Having a hard time searching through google and apache's site, could someone refresh my memory?

EDIT: Example, I'm using 'require_once "pdo-db-conn.php";' in a PHP file, but php-db-conn.php is actually outside the web root. The idea is that I don't need to list the external directory within my production php source code.

I've done it before, and it included listing directories which apache would search for files.

Comment: Are you talking about the PHP `include()` function? Or do you want to make files available to browsers *as if* they *were* in the web root?

Comment: Example, I'm using 'require_once "pdo-db-conn.php";' in a PHP file, but php-db-conn.php is actually outside the web root. The idea is that I don't need to list the external directory within my production php source code.

Answer (score 1):

For Apache, you are looking for either [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) or [`AliasMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html).

For PHP, you are looking for [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)

Comment: Aaah, that's my problem, it was php.ini, not httpd.conf. It was include_path that I was looking for. Thanks!